# How to extract non matching characters from two columns in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have two columns in SAS enterprise guide in which I have a list of characters. For example the 1st column may have 7 characters and the second column may also have 7 characters so they are a match. However, at times the columns do not match and I want to put the non-matching characters into a new column.
I have tried the find function.

```
   proc sql;
    create table Z
    as
    select *,
    case when (act_route_path<>designed_route_path) then 'Non Match'
    else 'Match' end as Off_at_Location_1
    from G;
    run;
```

The above code runs with no errors, however I don't want the bool true result to be 'Non Match'. I want it to tell me the non-matching characters. Is this doable in a case statement?

I do have two columns where my data is separated by (-), and can use these two columns for the output.

SEA-MDW-EFH-STL-----------SEA-POR-MDW-EFH-STL

In the above line, I want SAS to put in a new column, POR. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When they don't match are they like 'ABCDEFG' and 'ABCDEFGHIJ' so what is not matching is just the 'HIJ', or are they like 'ABCDEFG' and 'HIJKLMNO' where they don't match at all?

Comment: It's not clear what you want here so it's hard to say. Post an example of what your data looks like and what you want as output.

Comment: Does the *list* have a delimiter ?  Do the characters have to match at the same positions ?  Do you want a result such as `-<list of characters from 1 not in 2> +<list of characters from 2 not in 1>`

Comment: The list does have a delimeter (-).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this Red?

```
data g; 
    length act_route_path $ 2 designed_route_path $ 2;`
    input act_route_path $ designed_route_path $;
datalines;
    xx xy
    xx xx
    yy yy
    yx yy
;
run;

proc sql; create table z as
    select act_route_path, designed_route_path, 
        case when Off_at_Location_1 = 0 and substr2 = 0 then designed_route2 
            else 'Match' end as result
    from(select *
        ,case when act_route_path = designed_route_path then 1 else 0 end as Off_at_Location_1

        ,substr(act_route_path,1,1) as act_route1
        ,substr(act_route_path,1,2) as act_route2
        ,substr(designed_route_path,1,1) as designed_route1
        ,substr(designed_route_path,2,1) as designed_route2

        ,index(substr(act_route_path,1,1),substr(designed_route_path,1,1)) as substr1
        ,index(substr(act_route_path,2,1),substr(designed_route_path,2,1)) as substr2
    from g
)a
;
quit;
```

If you post the data can make the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: I will try this code and determine if it works. I have never attempted this, so not sure exactly what code I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compress` to do essentially an anti-join comparison of the two route values

```
data have;
  input route1 $8. route2 $8.; datalines;
ABCDEFGH CDEFGHI
ACEGI    BCDEFGHI
ABCD     EFGH
1234     1234
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select route1, route2
  , case 
      when route1=route2 then 'Same route'
      else 
        'diff:' 
        || '-' || trim(compress(route1, route2))  /* chars in 1 not in 2 */
        || '+' || trim(compress(route2, route1))  /* chars in 2 not in 1 */
    end  as route_compare length=25
  from have;
```

Comment: I will try this code as well and report back. Thanks!